# Sublayers/subgroups under single item in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, group-layer

We would like to develop hierarchies for viewing layers in our ArcGIS Server based IMS. The best solution to do this has been so far to create groups and sub-groups in ArcGIS Desktop before publishing services. However, with this approach we cannot create groups under single items (shapefile/feature class/raster). We would like to do this as it would reduce the amount useless groups and thus useless headers. Is this possible and how could it be done?

I might also be on completely wrong tracks, when I try to do this in Desktop before publishing the service. Feel free to share if you have any other approaches.